# Django - TypeError on deserializing json from jQuery POST

Tags: django, json

I'm pushing a fair amount of data via jQuery Ajax to a Django app in the form of JSON.  The data is received by the server, but I can't parse it.

In my views file, I have

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import simplejson

def saveStrategy(request):
  if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"response" : "failure"}))
  else:

    #This section here throws a TypeError - Expected String or Buffer
    #update_tasks = simplejson.loads(request.POST.get("tasks", False))
    #update_strategy = simplejson.loads(request.POST.get("strategy", False))

    update_strategy = request.POST.get("strategy", False)
    update_tasks = request.POST.get("tasks", False)

    print update_strategy

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"response" : "success"}))
```

which is the destination of

```
if (typeof currentTaskId !== "undefined") {
    $("#save_strategy_task").trigger("click");
    localTasks = JSON.stringify(tasks)
}
else
    localTasks = {};

.ajax({
    url : "saveStrategy/",
    type : "POST",
    data : {"strategy" : JSON.stringify(strategy), "tasks" : localTasks},
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data) {
        if (data.response == "success")
            strategyDetailCloseHandler();
    }
});
```

Now, when `update_strategy` is not involved with `simplejson`, I get

```
{
 "title":"Title",
 "status":"pending",
 "strategy":"Strategy",
 "dueDate":"",
 "owner":"",
 "metrics":"test",
 "id":"3",
 "outcome":"Outcome1"
}
```

However, if I try

```
print update_strategy["id"]
```

I get `TypeError: string indices must be integers` error.

How can I parse the incoming JSON to update the existing model object?

Comment: what is `strategy_update` ?

Comment: A typo, fixed now and double checked with my existing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues in the code relating to expected types of variables.  For example, in the JavaScript snippet, `localTasks` may be either a JavaScript object `{}`, or it may be a string from `JSON.stringify(tasks)`.

When this is POSTed to the server, there is a call

```
update_tasks = simplejson.loads(request.POST.get("tasks", False))
```

which has the potential to return a boolean value `False` if `tasks` isn't present in the response.

What I believe is happening is this:

1. On the client, `localTasks = {}`.
2. When the `.ajax` call occurs, it doesn't know how to handle the `tasks` entry because `.ajax` expects key/value pairs and so it doesn't even send the contents of `tasks` to the server.
3. The `update_tasks = simplejson.loads(request.POST.get("tasks", False))` code on the server attempts to look up `tasks` but `tasks` isn't in `request.POST` so `False` is returned.
4. The JSON parser attempts to do a `loads(False)`, resulting in your error.

To fix these issues:

1. Always have `localTasks` converted to a consistent type on the client. ie Ensure that it has been converted to a string.
2. Don't do `request.POST.get('foo', False)`.  Instead, do `request.POST.get('foo', '')` and handle the error case when an empty string is returned.